# Which file system must be chosen for /home directory at a notebook?

Tags: linux, filesystems

For a time im reading about filesystems that should be better for me but i still can't find my filesystem for /home.My criterias as follows:

1.Battery life
2.Reliability
3.Fastness

which fs do you should ? i see that btrfs's compression feature can make your notebook lose power but also i see btrfs is rock solid.

my choices as follows:
/ jfs
/boot ext2
/var reiser4 with noatime option

also im curious about nilfs2 what about that ? how is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use such, let's say, exotic filesystems (for a notebook)?

btrfs compression is disabled by default. I would stay with xfs, ext4 or btrfs. They are all used and developed heavily and broad support (means much testing, fast bug fixing) and xfs and ext4 are old enough.

The last one is problematic because it's relatively new. So, I don't think "rock solid" is the best to describe btrfs. Anyhow, I use it on all my machines. And snapshots are great for backups.

And I am pretty sure the filesystem has hardly any effect on the battery life.